# SPRING BOOT (with JWT) :Spring Security circular bean dependency

Tags: spring-boot

I'm currently Implementing Token and Role Base Authentication Using Spring Boot JWT MySQL following [this tutorial](https://github.com/codegymdanang/CGDN-SpringBoot-JWT-MySql/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo) authentication with Spring Security for REST API using Spring Boot

And I have an error:

```
Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   jwtRequestFilter (field private com.dating.service.impl.JwtUserDetailsService com.dating.config.JwtRequestFilter.jwtUserDetailsService)
┌─────┐
|  jwtUserDetailsService (field private org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder com.dating.service.impl.JwtUserDetailsService.passwordEncoder)
↑     ↓
|  webSecurityConfig (field private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.dating.config.WebSecurityConfig.jwtUserDetailsService)
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    /**
     * method authenticationManagerBean()
     * Create ThienBB
     * Date 13-11-2023
     * param N/A
     * return authenticationManagerBean()
     */
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * method passwordEncoder()
     * Create ThienBB
     * Date 13-11-2023
     * param N/A
     * return new BCryptPasswordEncoder()
     */
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * method configure()
     * Create ThienBB
     * Date 13-11-2023
     * param HttpSecurity
     * return void
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/public/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/member/**").hasAnyRole("MEMBER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

with Abstract Class: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated

**JwtRequestFilter**

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;


    /**
     * method doFilterInternal - Get Jwt and saving data to contextHolder
     * Create ThienBB
     * Date 13-11-2023
     * param HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain
     * return void
     */
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        //get headed without "Bearer", only take the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("Request Token Header it not begin with 'Bearer' String!");
        }

        //when get the token, we validation it
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**JwtUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    

    @Autowired
    private IAccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account existedAccount = this.accountRepository.findAccountByUserNameAndAndIsDeletedIsFalse(username);

        if (existedAccount == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username: " + username + " was not found in database");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                existedAccount.getUserName(),
                existedAccount.getPassword(),
                new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that your `JwtUserDetailsService` relies on a `PasswordEncoder` (even though you didn't show that code). The `PasswordEncoder` is defined in `WebSecurityConfig`, but to initialize `WebSecurityConfig`, it already needs the `JwtUserDetailsService`. So there is your cyclic dependency. The easiest way to resolve that is by moving the `PasswordEncoder` bean to a different configuration class. This solution and other alternatives can be found in the duplicate.

Comment: Thank for your help!